# Line break doesn't work in MailMessage's body

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

I'm sending an email from ASP.NET using MailMessage and SmtpClient. I want to introduce some line breaks but none of the following worked:

- Adding  tags `sbBody.Append("<table width='100%'><tr><td></br></br>");`
- Adding \r\n `sbBody.Append("<table width='100%'><tr><td>\r\n\r\n");`
- Appending a new line to the StringBuilder.

sbBody is a StringBuilder wich I use at the end to set MailMessage's body: `mailMessage.Body = sbBody.ToString()`

What Am I missing here? I'm viewing the emails in Outlook and off course I'm setting IsBodyHtml to true.

Thanks for your time.

**EDIT:** Solved, it was a syntax error, `</br>` instead of `<br/>`

Comment: Sometimes you have to tell Outlook to show additional line breaks.

Comment: These SO answers might be helpful:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/247546/outlook-autocleaning-my-line-breaks-and-screwing-up-my-email-format

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/136052/how-do-i-format-a-string-in-an-email-so-outlook-will-print-the-line-breaks

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3931409/mailmessage-sent-string-as-body-without-newline-in-outlook

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your br tags are wrong. They should be written as:

```
<br />
```

Comment: @daniloquio: Happens to the best of us.